# Storing binary blobs efficiently in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, base64, blob

<sub>(Please note I am aware Elasticsearch isn't the best option for storing binary blobs, but please bear with me :) )</sub>

Elasticsearch supports storing binary data using the `binary` datatype. The client sends a base64-encoded string representing the binary value.

Suppose I would like to store binary values efficiently in Elasticsearch storage-wise. In order to do so I can start by excluding the binary field from the `_source` in the mapping, so the base64 value isn't saved on disk inside the JSON.

I can then set `store: true` on the binary field to be able to fetch it later. But my question is:

Does Elasticsearch store `binary` data (when `store` is `true`) as base64 strings, or does it decode the data before storing it?

Answer (score 0):

Base64 values are decoded to byte[] for storing into doc_values or field

Answer (score 0):

If you use JSON to send you data to ES, you have to base64 encode binary data. If your field is of type 'binary', the base64 transported value will be decoded into binary and stored as that.

On a side note:
If you plan storing larger blobs, you can should consider using CBOR or SMILE. Both formats allow you to avoid the base64 encoding of your binary data.
ES understands 'Content-Type: application/cbor' and 'Content-Type: application/smile'. The format of the response can be controlled in a similar way by setting the 'Accept:' request header to 'application/json', 'application/cbor' or application/smile'.

Example:

```
curl ES_URL -u 'user:password' -X GET -H 'Accept: application/smile' | xxd
```